# EclipseLink "cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH" not cascading entityManager.refresh()

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I have a simple JPA mapping where everything works fine except that refresh is not being cascaded to child entities.

Here is my relevant code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "prospection")
public class ProspectionImpl extends AbstractIdentifiedObject<Prospection> implements Prospection {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = ProspectionLocationImpl.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = 
    CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "prospection_id")
    @JoinFetch(JoinFetchType.OUTER)
    private Collection<Location> locations = new ArrayList<Location>();
}
```

And my bean ProspectionLocationImpl is as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "prospection_perimetre")
public class ProspectionLocationImpl extends AbstractIdentifiedObject<ProspectionLocationImpl>
implements Location {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = CityImpl.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
    @JoinColumn(name = "commune_id")
    @JoinFetch(JoinFetchType.INNER)
    private City city;
}
```

Now for some reason I need to do a refresh on my ProspectionImpl bean, so I do it with :

```
entityManager.refresh(prospection);
```

The result is a refreshed `ProspectionImpl` bean but the same collection of `locations` with empty City information (except ID). Now in my test I have a non empty list of Location so I tried to do manually:

```
entityManager.refresh(prospection.getLocations().iterator().next());
```

And it works fine, my City is now filled with all data from the database.

I have the feeling that my "CascadeType.ALL" is not cascading the refresh. I tried `cascade = { CascadeType.ALL, CascadeType.REFRESH}` to explicitly set REFRESH cascading, but I could not find anything that cascades the REFRESH.

Am I doing something wrong?
Is there a global EclipseLink setting to unable REFRESH cascading?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What you are trying to do seems legit. I suspect this is a bug.

Comment: It's a bug, reported here https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=532251 unfortunately no response as of today. Luckily it's not that bad of a workaround to refresh the children.